# Вопрос по WinAPI функциям GetExtendedUdpTable и GetExtendedTcpTable

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Есть следующие функции в WinApi:

```
   [DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern uint GetExtendedUdpTable(IntPtr pUdpTable,
       ref int pdwSize,
       bool bOrder,
       uint ulAf,
       UDP_TABLE_CLASS TableClass,
       uint Reserved
       )
       ;

      [DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern uint GetExtendedTcpTable(IntPtr pTcpTable,
       ref int pdwSize,
       bool bOrder,
       uint ulAf,
       TCP_TABLE_CLASS TableClass,
       uint Reserved
       )
       ;
```

Все параметры понятны, кроме одного - ulAf. Как написано в MSDN - это версия IP, используемая конечной(-ми) точкой(-ми). Если передать в любую из функций AF_INET, то вернется одно кол-во тэйблов с IP, а если передать AF_INET6, то вернется совершенно другое. Мне кажется, грубо говоря, AF_INET и AF_INET6 нужны для получения соединений IPv4 и IPv6. Прав ли я?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Если передать в любую из функций AF_INET, то вернется одно кол-во тэйблов с IP, а если передать AF_INET6, то вернется совершенно другое.

Так и должно быть, потому что IPv4 и IPv6 (как вы правильно предположили) — это два абсолютно разных протокола, образующих совершенно независимые наборы соединений.

Более того, возвращаемое количество также зависит и от того, какой список запрашиваете, то есть какое значение параметра `TableClass` передаёте. Ведь эти функции могут возвращать не только соединения различных видов, но и процессы, которым они принадлежат.

Comment: получается чтобы получить все соединения, например, с протоколом udp, мне надо дважды вызвать функцию? например, сначала ipv4 адреса при помощи передачи AF_INET, а потом ipv6 при помощи AF_INET6?

Comment: @OlegLylok, именно. Операционная система разделяет IPv4 и IPv6, чтобы не сломать относительно старые программы, не умеющие работать с новой версией протокола. Так что во имя обратной совместимости надо получать IPv6-адреса отдельно.

Comment: только вот странно одно - при параметре AF_INET6, возвращаются тэйблы, адрес которых, если превратить в строку не вида ipv6, а ipv4 - 133.202.248.196 (пример из вывода). преобразовывал данные через IPAddress; Правильно ли это?

Comment: @OlegLylok, что вы передаёте конструктору класса `IPAddress`? Массив `char[16]`?

Comment: uint dwLocalAddr

Comment: @OlegLylok, если вы передаёте `AF_INET6`, то out-поля `pUdpTable` и `pTcpTable` трактуются как указатели на другую структуру, `MIB_TCP6TABLE_OWNER_PID`/`MIB_UDP6TABLE_OWNER_PID`, и адрес будет в поле `ucLocalAddr`. Заодно надо изменить `TableClass` на `TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS`/`UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS` (вам же нужен список подключений к удалённым серверам, да?)

Comment: @OlegLylok, к слову, адрес `133.202.248.196` [принадлежит координационному центру сети Японии](https://www.reg.ru/whois/?check=&dname=133.202.248.196&_csrf=2f4f9376e21168a3241506c5b42aa15a), так что он точно не может быть вашим локальным.

Comment: а, я понял ошибку - использовал MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID вместо MIB_TCP6TABLE_OWNER_PID. Кстати, а какая структура возвращает всю инфу о соединениях, id процессах и т.д?

Comment: @OlegLylok, вот она (`MIB_*TABLE_OWNER_PID`) и есть. `dwOwningPid` - идентификатор процесса-владельца подключения (по которому можно открыть дескриптор и получить остальную информацию о процессе). А фильтр на возвращаемый список подключений определяется полем `TableClass`: `*_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS` для открытых программами на вашем компьютере, `*_TABLE_OWNER_PID_LISTENER` для открытых извне, `*_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL` для всех без разбору.

Comment: чего-то я не могу найти *_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS и тому подобное. можете скинуть ссылку на msdn?

Comment: @OlegLylok, звёздочка - это `TCP` или `UDP` (чтобы не писать постоянно `структура1`/`структура2`). То есть `TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS` или `UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS`. Ну и так далее, по аналогии. И да, с UDP ошибка вышла - там надо использовать константу `UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID`. Кстати, в MSDN всё расписано в описании функций `GetExtendedUdpTable()` и `GetExtendedTcpTable()`.

Comment: все, последний вопрос и я вас более не буду тревожить: для получения всех соединений (udp,tcp) нужно getextended*table и owner_pid и *row... для ipv6 *row6 ownerpid и те же функции, да?

Comment: @OlegLylok, да. Поэтому параметр `pUdpTable` и объявлен не как ссылка на структуру, а как абстрактный указатель, так как его смысл  в одной и той же функции меняется.

Comment: спасибо большое